# Access and save parent data in the child component laravel livewire issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am failing to access a parent data field in a child component, When I add it as a public property in a child component it erases the value on the form input. The amount field is returning an empty value when I set a public $amount property in the child component.

Parent view

```html
<div>
    @foreach ($products as $product)
        @livewire('orders', ['product'=> $product], key($product->id))
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Child view

```html
<div class="mt-8">
    <div class="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg bg-white">
        <div class="px-6 py-4">
            <div class="font-bold text-xl mb-2 ">{{$product->id}}</div>
            <hr><br>
            <p class="text-gray-700 text-base">

            <div class="font-bold text-lg mb-2">
                {{$product->amount}}
            </div>

            <div class="relative">
                <select wire:model="period" name="period"
                    class="block appearance-none w-full bg-white border border-gray-400 text-gray-700 py-3 px-4 pr-8 rounded leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-400">
                    <option value="5">5 Days</option>
                    <option value="7">7 Days</option>
                    <option value="10">10 Days</option>
                </select>
                @error('period')
                    <p class="mt-2 text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="relative">
                <input wire:model="amount"
                    class="appearance-none block w-full bg-white text-gray-700 border border-gray-400 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-400"
                    type="text" value="{{$product->amount}}">
                @error('amount')
                 <p class="mt-2 text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="px-6 py-4">
            <button wire:click.prevent="save({{$product->id}})"
                class="inline-block bg-purple-700 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-200 mr-2 transform motion-reduce:transform-none hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 transition ease-in-out duration-300">
                Bid
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Parent Component

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Product;
use App\User;

class Products extends Component
{
    public $products;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->products = Product::all();
    }


    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.products');
    }
}
```

Child Component

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Order;
use App\Product;

class Orders extends Component
{
    public $product, $period = 5, $productId, $amount;


    public function mount(Product $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    public function save($productId)
    {
        $product = Product::where('id', $productId)->first();
        $product->createOrders([
            'buyer_id' => auth()->user()->id,
            'product_id' => $this->productId,
            'period' => $this->period,
            'order_amount' => $this->amount,

        ]);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.orders');
    }
}
```

Comment: To those who might be experiencing the same issue, I managed to do a work-around,  I added the public $amount property in the parent Product component and I accessed in the orders component this way-- `'order_amount' =>Product::where('id', $productId)->first()->amount`, if there is any better  way of doing this, your help is much appreciated.